# Is OpenVG supported by video card vendors?

Tags: graphics, openvg

Is OpenVG supported by nVidia, AMD and Intel in their drivers? Will it be supported in future? I'm really interested in some sort of HW-accelerated text and SVG rendering.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVG#OpenVG_in_Hardware

Yes, but usually in embedded platforms.

Also, Amanith is a OpenGL/OpenGL ES implementation of OpenVG.

http://www.amanith.org/project.html

Comment: 1. I have seen OVG wiki page. There are Mesa3D library and Gallium drivers for nVidia/AMD/Intel cards, but the situation is NOT the same as with OpenGL drivers, when every vendor do its best to optimize them for the HW.

2. Amanith is just the same but it's also commercially licensed.

What I'd like to see is vendors implementation of an open standard for 2D graphics as we have for 3D.

Comment: Isn't that what the wikipedia page contains? It talks about VG HW implementations, such as the ARM Mali, Broadcom, Imagination PowerVR, etc. Those ARE implemetation of the OpenVG open standard.

If you want/need support directly from NV/AMD/Intel, i would say just "no". OpenVG is pretty unknown from their side.